# Detecting which Activity is Running at the Moment?

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect which activity is visible at the moment?

I have an activity that is launched whenever the server sends an asynchronous message, but if the user hasn't answered the previous message I don't want to take over the screen to display the new message. So I need to know if there is an Activity running of a particular type before launching.

I know I could just store this is inside the application, but I was wondering if there was a native way of doing it.

EDIT: And I do need this... so if you don't know the answer don't say "You will never need this"

EDIT 2: The application is not for the market, and its for a company that will have it running in the Galaxy Tab by itself

Thanks

Comment: can you describe more about your question ?

Comment: I'd like to reword the answer of @Vladimir. _You should never need it. Period._ Applications which are not yours aren't of your business neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Meh. here it is](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#topActivity). But what you are doing is just a [hack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey%28%29).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162659/best-way-to-accomplish-inter-activity-communication-in-an-android-tabhost-applica/1225005#1225005) is more likely to be the fix for your use-case. Use the Application class to keep a track of your app's current state.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. I tell you more: you won't ever need it.

Comment: This answer is kind of direct ^^ but i think that's the truth. What code should ever needs to know that except of the running activity which automaticly knows that by the fact that it's running at the moment.

Comment: I do need to know, thats why I asked it... I hate when I get this sort answer. if You don't know then just say it, but don't assume people are asking just for the sake of it.

Comment: Because I have an activity that shouldn't launch if another one is running.

Comment: Please, update your question and try to be more descriptive. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: exactly the same problem like me

Comment: Ant what about the case, when i have two class in my app, activity and broadcast reciever with google push notification and when i get the message. When i get the message from google can heppens two things: my activity was already removed from task by system (in this case i want put on front) or the activity is still in top and i dont want do nothnig. how i do this without i know is the activity is still working:)